# Will deleting questions with no comments or answers get me banned from asking?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, post-ban

Well, I guess the title says it all. Sometimes you post a question, and you realize the mistake only after posting it, when you are reading what you have posted.

For instance, you post the question and then find out that the issue was a missing bracket, or some other typo. Is it okay to delete the question then? If there were no comments(or may be 1 or 2) and NO answers.

Comment: If you noticed a mistake in the post, then edit it! Why delete it?

Comment: @10Rep  not a mistake in the post, I meant I figured the answer to the question., Sorry, was not clear in the question. Updated it.

Comment: Every question without a positive score (i.e. a score <= 0) count towards a question ban, so yes, they do.

Comment: If you find out the answer, then post a self answer. Don't delete it. That will lead to a ban, as @Tom said.

Comment: @10Rep Even if it was something silly like wrong indentation or maybe an extra space somewhere?

Comment: @AbhishekRai If it was a typo, then sure. But if it's not a closable question, and you figured out the answer, then pls post a self answer. That would be great and would count against a ban.

Comment: It's preferable that you rule out simple fixes like indentation errors or small typos before posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @10Rep Ah. Thanks. That I know. I was only concerned about silly errors that you sometimes figure out while reading your posted question.

Comment: @Spevacus ..I'm human, I make mistakes, :) Isn't that the whole point of SO?

Comment: See [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). As far as I can work out, closed counts, deleted counts, downvoted counts. All separately. Meaning a deleted post is better than a closed & downvoted one. I also believe that a score of -1 doesn't count as much as a score of -12. Note however that a closed & downvoted post is likely to *also* get deleted.

Comment: @Scratte But then a closed post will get roomba'd right? So it'll get deleted anyways.

Comment: @10Rep Depends if it has Answers, and what the score of those are. And if other users are putting delete votes on it in case the system doesn't delete it automatically.

Comment: @Scratte In this case, the user is deleting it straight away, so most probably no answers to the question.

Comment: @10Rep Someone edited my question. I clearly mentioned..If there were no comments(or may be 1 or 2) and NO answers.

Comment: @AbhishekRai Thanks for highlighting the editing done. I didn't realize that your scenario isn't at all about just a typo, but basically just changing your mind about posting your Question.

Comment: @AbhishekRai - Any question you submit will count towards or against your ability to submit new questions.  If a question is deleted, it will continue to be countered towards or against your ability, since it's been asked.  If you figured out the answer, you shouldn't delete it, you should submit an answer.  If it's a typo, well then shame on you, for submitting a question too early.  If you have submitted several questions, caused by intention or typos, then you should change your habit of asking questions too early.

Comment: @SecurityHound  That's a valid point, I guess, if it happens with someone more than twice.

Answer (score -2):

If you post your question and then realise that you figured out the answer, then you should post a self answer if your question is on-topic for SO. For instance, if the problem was a simple typo, then don't post an answer. Delete your question, as it is likely to be closed and deleted anyways. This is if you make a mistake in posting the question.

If your question is on-topic in accordance with all the help pages, then please do post a self answer. After all, it's more useful information for us, right?

If you do get banned, that means you need to contribute some good answers or good questions.

[To quote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

> The only way for the ban to be lifted is for you to start contributing positively to the site.

Most likely your post will have no answers (as you deleted it immediately) and there isn't much light shed on the banning system itself (to prevent gaming of the system), so this is just my advice:

> **Before posting a question, be sure that there are no syntaxical errors in your code.**

According to a moderator, it is theoretically possible for them to undelete, upvote, and delete your posts to get you out of a ban, but that would be seen as gaming of the system by many users, even for a good cause, so that's unlikely to happen.

It's hard to get out of a ban. See [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) for more detail.

<sub>I know you already know this, but for future readers: if you find a grammar mistake or something like that, please edit your question/answer. Don't delete it. We have an edit button for a reason.</sub>

Comment: Moderators cannot unban a Question ban. It's a system imposed ban. See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) Perhaps you can find some reference material, so it's clear where your information comes from? ;)

Comment: I don't think this addresses the ban issue much.  Key point is deletion is mostly irrelevant for the question ban (Shog9 had written about that previously but too busy to find the source).  The key thing with the ban is the votes.  Deleting doesn't change how the post counts towards except for one very specific scenario).

Comment: You edited in an example of a typo into the Question, that wasn't there to begin with, and you're answered partly saying to post a self-Answer if the problem wasn't a typo.. ?

Comment: @Scratte The typo was a mistake; not intentional at all.

Comment: Not addressing the typo made while editing in the example that the reason one may want to delete a Question is because of a typo in code. I was addressing the later :)